# My submenu items are not appearing in browser

Tags: html, menu, submenu

My submenu items from VIDEOS are not appearing in the browser. I believe I have coded them correctly already. I am not sure whether it is because I am trying to make a sub-menu when I have already coded CSS (making it more difficult) but I really need some help so they can appear. Upon that, I would code CSS to make it more user-friendly so when the mouse hovers over 'videos', the menu would cascade down. my link rel is correct. Many thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css" />
<title>Puppy Power</title>
</head>
<body>
        <div id="page">
<header></header>
        <div id="dog logo">
    </div>

<ul id="navigation">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="Videos.html">Videos</a>
            <ul class="sub">
                <li><a href="#">Vines</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Pugs</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Failing Dogs</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Crazy Dogs</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Funny Dogs</a></li>

            </ul>
        </li>


        <li><a href="#">Photographs</a></li>    
        <li><a href="#">Articles</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>

<div id="hero"><h1><b>HERO</b></h1></div>


<div id="topvideo"><h1><b>TOP VIDEO</b></h1></div>

<div id="topphoto"><h1><b>TOP PHOTO</b></h1></div>

<div id="toparticles"><h1><b>TOP ARTICLE</b></h1></div>

<div id="content"><h1><b>CONTENT</b></h1></div>

<div id="footer"><h1><b>FOOTER</b></h1></div>

</body>
</html>

    #page {
    max-width: 850px;
    min-width: 840px;
    min-height: 1550px;
    max-height: 1600px;
} 




ul {
    width: 813px;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
    border-top: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-left: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-right: 1px solid #89cff0;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
    display:inline-block;


}

li {
    display: inline;
    text-decoration: none;



}

#hero {
    width: 813px;
    height: 408px;
    border-top: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-left: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-right: 1px solid #89cff0;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 5px 0px 0px 0px;
    text-align: center;
    color: red;

}

#topvideo {
    width: 267px;
    height: 370px;
    border-top: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-left: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-right: 1px solid #89cff0;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 5px 0px 5px 0px;



}

#topphoto {
    width: 267px;
    height: 370px;
    border-top: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-left: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-right: 1px solid #89cff0;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 5px 0px 5px 0px;

}

#toparticles {
    width: 267px;
    height: 370px;
    border-top: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-left: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-right: 1px solid #89cff0;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
}

#content {
    width: 813px;
    height: 310px;
    border-top: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-left: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-right: 1px solid #89cff0;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    text-align: center;
}

#footer {

    width: 813px;
    height: 100px;
    border-top: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-left: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-right: 1px solid #89cff0;
    margin: 5px 0px 0px 0px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Replica of the question code: http://jsfiddle.net/wh2Wq/

Answer (score 0):

A good way to debug is to strip it down and see whats working and what is not.  Try removing the class="sub" and all of the a tags and see if its working then.  Then you will be able to identify the problem.